# Obtaining values for Dynamic checkboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox

I'm pretty new at web development. So, sorry if this I'm asking dumb questions. I'm building a list of checkboxes based on available filter criteria pulled from a database. The model i pass to my view has a property

```
 public List<string> ServicesList{ get; set; }
```

My view code contains a loop to create a checkbox for each item in the list.

```
            @foreach (string svc in Model.ServicesList)
            {
                if (svc != "")
                {
                    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedServices" title="@svc" value="@svc" checked="checked" /> @svc
                    <br />
                }
            }
```

My Controller Action looks like this:

```
 public ActionResult ServiceListExplorer(string[] SelectedServices, FormCollection fc)
 {
 }
```

This works as far as displaying the list of services as checkboxes and having access inside the controller action  to which ones are checked by the user once the httppost occurs. But, I have 2 questions:

1. How can I pass which items should be checked initially via the Model? This would allow me to save off their filter criteria and pre-select the services. I was thinking maybe I need to use a SelectList instead of List but not really sure how.
2. How can I make the "checked" attribute dynamic by binding it to a value in the model?

Comment: You should have two lists: One with all of the available options, and the other one that has a list of what they've selected.

Comment: Check this link : http://sampathloku.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-use-checkboxlistfor-with-aspnet.html   you can use a CheckBoxListFor Plugin

Answer (score 1):

First of all instead of ServicesList should be list of objects not list of string :

```
    public class Service
    {
    public string ServiceName {get; set;}
    public bool isChecked {get;set;}

    }
    ....
    public List<Service> ServicesList{ get; set; }
    ....
    //that controller will collect data posted from view 
    //(your form will post only checked checkboxes)
    [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Update(FormCollection services)
        {

            foreach (string item in services)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item);
            }

            return Json(services);


        }
```

not in your view :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) { 
foreach (MvcMusicStore.Models.Service svc in Model)
            {

        @svc.ServiceName    @Html.CheckBox(svc.ServiceName, svc.isChecked); 
    <br/>

            }
            <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
}
```

Comment: This works fine for pre-checking items but how does this report back to the controller as to which items were checked/unchecked by the user?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a list of string objects, you should define a class for e.g.

```
public class ServiceObject
{
  public string Name{get;set;}
  public bool IsChecked{get;set;}
}
```

then your code will become-

```
public List<ServiceObject> ServicesList{ get; set; }
```

what you have to fill is the `IsChecked` property to true if your checkbox is to be selected:

then this line will become-

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedServices" title="@svc" value="@svc" checked=Model.IsChecked />
```